# RAIDCORE Configuration SCSI Processor Device - Driver - After Instalation - DELL T150

Tags: windows, dell, windows-server-2022

I have purchased a DELL PowerEdge T150 server.

During the installation of Windows (Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard, Version: 10.0.20348 Build 20348), Installer did not see a matrix with disks. So I used the driver which I [downloaded from the Dell website](https://www.dell.com/support/home/pl-pl/product-support/product/poweredge-t150/drivers) on Pendrive and it solved the problem.

Additionally, I installed the other drivers from the site: [Official site with drivers](https://www.dell.com/support/home/pl-pl/product-support/product/poweredge-t150/drivers)

However, in Device Manager, I have a question mark next to RAIDCORE Configuration SCSC Processor Device and I don't know what driver is missing.

[image: Device Manager - screenshot]

Here comes the question:
Is it a driver that I installed during Windows or a completely different one? I am asking for help in indicating the appropriate driver that I should install.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing on an R720. I believe it is related to the built-in SCSI controller on the Motherboard. Most likely (at least in my case) there is a separate controller card and you can ignore the device. Leave it alone unless you need it. Don't try to activate it, or install a driver, etc. Useless waste of resources if you don't use it.